# Why did my app name not change on my device?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I launched an app a couple of years ago.

The app re-branded. Owned by the same company. We renamed the app in the App Store. Logo updated.

In App Store Connect, iTunes, etc. I see the new app name. In Test Flight, the new name is shown.

Additionally, the various spots within the app (like the Display Name) and other internal areas where the name were used were all updated.

However, in my Settings app, and on my device where the icon and app name are, the *old* name is still shown.

Why is this? Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the app in App Store Connect is purely for the name used on the product page on the App Store.

The name of the app when installed on device is controlled by the display name of the app written into the app bundle downloaded by the device. Change this in the Display Name field of the target settings in Xcode.

Comment: The Display Name was changed when we renamed the app. I have verified this by loading the app in Xcode, going to the main .xcodeproj file and under General, Targets the Display name is correct (the new value).

Comment: I think you need to change a setting in the Info.plist.  Take a look in there and see if the old name is visible.  Also, do a search for the old name in the entire project and see where it's being used.

Comment: I have done a search. Cannot find the name anywhere.